# Is there any way to make cursor smooth caret animation like VSCode while typing?

Tags: css, animation, cursor, smoothing, caret

I want to make **cursor smooth caret animation effect like Visual Studio Code**

So I searched on google about it but I din't find expected answer.
If you still don't understand what I am talking about kindly watch [this video](https://youtu.be/1EosrFTKggE)

I really want to add this effect on my website

I tried

```css
* {
   transition: all 80ms;
}
```

But it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use for my vscode. Just install `Custom CSS and JS Loader` and follow the installation instruction then put this css in your css file that you will link while following the extension instruction.

```css
.monaco-editor .cursors-layer.cursor-smooth-caret-animation > .cursor {
    transition: all 0.17s !important;
}
```

`transition: all 80ms` is the default [style](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/23a3c6ec3e5cdc2f7880cb0cf477380ee38ef88e/src/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/viewCursors/viewCursors.css#L17) used by VScode. You can try setting from `0.15s` to `0.2s` so it will look smooth.